# Selenium 2.0 C# как остановить ожидание загрузки страницы

Tags: selenium

Добрый день

При отладке сайта встретил проблему загрузки страницы при обращении к файсбуку, т.е. страница полностью загружается но браузер пишет что "Ожидание загрузки от facebook.com" данная запись висит часами в результате программа пишет что таймаут загрузки страницы и не выполняет код дальше. Перерыл весь инет но так и не нашел решения этой проблемы. Можно браузеру как то передать команду СТОП? Либо IWebDriver передать команду что страница загружена?

Comment: Проверь мой ответ. Он явно рабочий т.к. я им пользовался много раз.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, здесь самым простым будет отлавливать TimeoutException:

```
 WebDriver wd;
 //... Инициализируем наш драйвер wd и поставим таймаут
 wd.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

 try {
     wd.get(url);
     break;
 } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException te) {
     ((JavascriptExecutor)wd).executeScript("window.stop();");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

в нужном месте

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Brwsr.Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.stop();");
```